# Select JOIN table using Linq and QueryExpression

Tags: c#, sql, .net, linq, dynamics-crm

I have this:

```
QueryExpression query = new QueryExpression("entity1");
query.ColumnSet = new ColumnSet(true);

LinkEntity accountLink = query.AddLink("entity2", "entity1id", "entity1id", JoinOperator.Inner);
accountLink.Columns = new ColumnSet(true);
accountLink.EntityAlias = "e2";

...

EntityCollection entities = service.RetreiveMultiple(query);
```

Lets say there is more joins and conditions in the `query`, but for us is important just this `JOIN`.
Now I want to get `IEnumerable<Entity>` with `entity2` instances from `query`. How can I do it? I'm thinking about using Linq, but I dont know how excatly  write the command. I want something like this:

```
IEnumerable<Entity> entities2 = from entity in entities.Entities
                                          ?? e2 ???
                                          select ??;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example D365 LINQ query including joins with late bound entities:

```
public JsonResult Offices()
{    
    var connectionString = @"SET YOUR CONNECTION STRING";
    var svc = new CrmServiceClient(connectionString); 
    var list = new List<KeyValuePair<Guid, string>>();
    using (var context = new Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.OrganizationServiceContext(svc))
    {           
        var result = (from a in context.CreateQuery("account")
                      join o in context.CreateQuery("opportunity")
                      on a.GetAttributeValue<Guid>("accountid") equals o.GetAttributeValue<Guid>("new_igoffice")
                      where a.GetAttributeValue<OptionSetValue>("statecode").Value == 0
                      where o.GetAttributeValue<Guid>("parentaccountid") != Guid.Empty
                      orderby a.GetAttributeValue<string>("name")
                      select new KeyValuePair<Guid, string>(a.GetAttributeValue<Guid>("accountid"), a.GetAttributeValue<string>("name")))
                      .Distinct();

        list.AddRange(result);
    }
    return Json(list, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```